# Why fedora can't load module-detect?

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio

I have installed fedora yesterday. I was using arch all my linux-life, fedora is good too. But I have only one problem. For using my headpanel analog sound i run script with pulseaudio module setup:

```
pactl load-module module-detect
```

But it doesn't work on Fedora. I have an error every time:

```
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

What i need to do?

Comment: If I understand correctly, on systems with `udev`, [`module-detect`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-detect) is deprecated in favor of `module-udev-detect`.  There's a good chance `module-udev-detect` is already loaded.  Have you checked by looking at, e.g., `pactl list short modules | grep detect` ?

Comment: `module-udev-detect` give error too